# WSO2 Stream processor 4.4.0 - Two file source

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

Can you help me please?
I'm trying create a simple siddhi app on wso2 sp 4.4.0. I'm trying to load two files from two folders and after loading the data, the file will be deleted but only one folder is loaded.the second folder is not loaded.  Do you know how i can working  with two files please?

My siddhi app

```
@App:name("SiddhiApp")
@App:description("SiddhiApp / test")


@source(type='file', mode='LINE',
    dir.uri='file://C:\Users\john\wso2sp-test\firstFolder',
    tailing='false',
        action.after.process='delete',
    @map(type='csv',delimiter=";"))
define stream filestream (name string, surname string);

@source(type='file', mode='LINE',
    dir.uri='file://C:\Users\john\wso2sp-test\secondFolder',
    tailing='false',    
    action.after.process='delete',
    @map(type='csv',delimiter=";"))
define stream filestreamSec (id string, name string);

@sink(type='log')
define stream logStream(id string, name string); 

from filestreamSec
select *
insert into logStream;   

from filestream
select *
insert into logStream;
```

Comment: Is the siddhi app deploying successfully? I see the logStream definition and filestream is different

Comment: yes, its successfull

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed several bugs after the siddhi-io-file-1.1.1.jar which we released with wso2sp-4.4.0.
The current stable version is siddhi-io-file-2.0.10.

I did check your scenario and it works with the latest siddhi-io-file-2.0.10 version.

This can be used with wso2si-1.0.0. This io-file version cannot be used with wso2sp-4.4.0 because there are major API changes with the siddhi version used with io-file-2.0.10 and which is packed in the distribution.

FYI: [WSO2 Streaming Integrator](https://wso2.com/integration/streaming-integrator/) is the successor if WSO2 Stream Processor.

Comment: While helping individuals, we also try to produce a permanent source of future help for others - so answers that produce a tangible record are preferred. Before offering 1:1 help, read [this Meta post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280603) and reconsider making the effort to document the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does not work, SP can check always only one directory at a time. Even if you create separate siddhi apps.
This feature is really missing.